# Debounce method implementation in Javascript is not getting console

Tags: javascript, html, debouncing

Following is my code implementation for which debounce in JavaScript is not working. I am trying to execute the function only after 3 sec delay. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Code -**

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    if(timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(fn, delay);
  }
}

const myinp = document.getElementById('myinp');

if(myinp) {
  myinp.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log(`Console Value =>`, e.target.value)
    debounce(function() {
    console.log(`++++`) // This console is not working 
    }, 3000)
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

Comment: Note that in your example, `debounce` returns an anonymous function, which is then not called anywhere.

Comment: @OlegBarabanov How to use it then ?

Comment: I wrote an example [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427517/debounce-method-implementation-in-javascript-is-not-getting-console/77427596#77427596).

Comment: @Nesh Where did you get the `debounce` implementation from? Did that source explain how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your example, `debounce()` returns an anonymous function, which is then not called anywhere.

Slightly modified example below (but using [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to assign the appropriate `this`):

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeout;

  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), delay);
  };
}

const myinp = document.getElementById('myinp');

if (myinp) {
  myinp.addEventListener('input', debounce(function(e) {
    console.log(`++++`)
  }, 3000))
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

Comment: `timeout` should not be made a global variable.

Comment: @Bergi , I agree with you. I added one of the available implementations without using a global variable (since it can be implemented in many ways).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Oleg went for such a long answer (even showing the global anti-pattern). All you needed to do is use your `debounce` function API properly. That is, have a reference to the `debounced` function and call it in your event listener.

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    if(timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(fn, delay);
  }
}

const myinp = document.getElementById('myinp');

if(myinp) {
  const debounced = debounce(function() {
    console.log(`++++`) // This console is now working 
  }, 3000)

  myinp.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    console.log(`Console Value =>`, e.target.value)
    debounced();
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

Comment: Dunno, on mobile at least it won’t run as a snippet.

Comment: that is strange, haven't tried it on mobile but on desktop was a bit slow to me when I posted it (and I don't mean the needed wait of 3 seconds before the console executes).

Comment: Tried it in Chrome on Android and it seems to work (as mentioned there's the 3 seconds delay from the debounce)

Comment: Script error iOS chrome, safari seems to not error at least.